# Can Putty SSH to my rpi, but ios SSH client fails on my home network

Tags: ssh

I have a RPI 3B+.  Everything is wifi connected to a modern Netgear 'Orbi' router.  I can ssh to my rpi via putty client on my pc. No problem.  I try to ssh via the 'termius' app on my iphone and it always says, "connection closed w/ error: host unreachable."

I have confirmed that both my phone and the pc are on the home network (I can put the phone into airplane mode to guarantee it).  I also am using the correct ip address.

There are tons of old "cannot ssh" postings on here, but they're mainly > 5 years old, referring to ancient RPIs.  Any idea what this modern configuration is not working?   I've tried tkilling the putty ssh session in case the rpi doesn't tolerate multiple ssh's, but that didn't cure anything.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

============================

Ljm Dullart asked if i can  ping the phone/rpi and what 'arp -a' shows.

This is my router's attached devices:

[image]

The iphone can ping the rpi
[image]

the rpi can ping the iphone
[image]

`arp -a` output only lists a few of the devices on the attached-device list (highlighted with red check marks)

[image]
Continue to be unable to SSH over to RPI.

=====================

```
PING 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=232 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=62.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=102 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=39.2 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.5 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 7ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 39.182/109.004/232.034/74.514 ms
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ traceroute 192.168.1.5
traceroute to 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5)  89.378 ms  87.606 ms  88.751 ms
```

I do see the phone on the pi's arp table now, but am still unable to ssh:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arp -a
? (192.168.1.6) at 28:80:88:2e:ba:67 [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.1.1) at 28:80:88:2f:2b:14 [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.1.7) at 04:ed:33:c4:b7:6a [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.1.5) at 46:c3:75:5b:2b:47 [ether] on wlan0
```

Comment: could it be some type of router isolation setting that applies to wireless but lets any wired have access to any wireless?

Comment: Can de Pi see the Iphone and vice versa? Do you have a `ping` app on the Iphone and does that see the Pi? And can your Pi ping the Iphone? Or, when the ping fails, can you see the MAC of the Iphone in the `arp -a` output on the Pi (after you tried the ping)?

Comment: @LjmDullaart ping works in both directions. However the `arp -a` output doesn't show the iphone.  See all details in my edited post.

Comment: Can you put in text in stead of picture of screen shots?https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: That is odd: if they're both on the same L2 network, the phone should be in the arp table. Can you `traceroute` the phone from the Pi?   (I have no experience with the orbi, but it seems more a network issue than a raspberry Pi issue)

Comment: @LjmDullaart   Again this afternoon now i can see the iphone on the arp table, but the SSH connection to it still fails.  (edited post to show this as text)